# how to do conditional maxlength in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-scope

does anyone know how to do conditional maxlength in angularjs, I have found conditional required but not maxlength etc....

for example if maxlength given ...it should validate but if maxlength is 0 or false, it should not....

```
$scope.validation = {a: {required:true,minlength:5, maxlength:10}, 
                     b: {required:false,minlength:0, maxlength:false}}
```

Html gets created using ng-repeat loop....n now problem is maxlength gets fired everytime...whereas i have disabled it for second input field

```
<input type="text" name="myName" ng-model="name" ng-minlength='validation.a.minlength' ng-maxlength="validation.a.maxlength" ng-required='validation.a.required'  />


<input type="text" name="myName1" ng-model="name1" ng-minlength='validation.b.minlength' ng-maxlength="validation.b.maxlength" ng-required='validation.b.required' />
```

Comment: You can not add conditional attribute in angularjs. I also wanted conditional attributes, but they are not supporting this. You have to use ng-if or ng-show to handle your requirement..

Comment: Have you tried using `maxlength="{{validation.a.maxlength}}"` instead of `ngMaxlength` directive?

Comment: Naeramarth - First thing wat you are saying is a input restriction not a validation of input. Secondly it will also force max length it won't allow you disable to maxlength factor

Comment: FYI -- there is an angularjs module that builds your form from provided metadata -- so no need to  https://github.com/JustMaier/angular-autoFields-bootstrap

Comment: Can anyone tell me difference between using ng-required='validation.a.required' and ng-required='{{validation.a.required}}' because both works

Answer (score 2):

These parameters seems to work, if you use empty strings as "false" via angular expressions.

```
<input type="text" name="myName" ng-model="name" ng-minlength='{{validation.a.minlength}}' ng-maxlength="{{validation.a.maxlength}}" ng-required='validation.a.required'  />
<input type="text" name="myName1" ng-model="name1" ng-minlength='{{validation.b.minlength}}' ng-maxlength="{{validation.b.maxlength}}" ng-required='validation.b.required' />

  $scope.validation = {
    a: {required:true, minlength:5, maxlength:10}, 
    b: {required:false, minlength:'', maxlength:''}
  }
```

<strike>[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/eRFe5VJguBUHa4Wsd9pQ?p=preview)</strike>

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2SpHJqObA6oxEjzm9J1C?p=preview) for 1.3.2

Now its possible to use 0 and [Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) to ignore this rules. Or maybe just 999 will be enough :)

```
 b: {required:false, minlength:0, maxlength:Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER}
```

Comment: Thats great Breath....thank you and I agree with your example at plunker, but am bit surprised I tried your idea of empty strings, still it dint work for me....it just throws too long error on entering first alphabet....but same is working at plunker

Comment: This does not seem to work with later versions of angular. Changing the plunker to 1.3.1 for instance produces the OP's problem again

Comment: Things look more natural with the 1.3